# Who proved that the plane partition generating function is valid?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, partitions, young-tableaux

I know Major Macmahon conjectured the formula $$ \prod_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-q^m)^m}=1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty PL(n)q^n$$
but who was the first to prove it?

Comment: I think you should split-off as a separate question (or omit) the 'bonus points' questions. 
IMO this mix of precise and broad, does in general not work well in *one* question.

Comment: That has been done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is MacMahon himself, who proved this in his book *Combinatory Analysis* as a corollary of a more general theorem about plane partitions.  See Sections IX and X.

There is some additional historical information in the Notes to Chapter 7 of Richard Stanley's book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, volume 2.

Comment: I have not read this section of MacMahon's book carefully, but many of his proofs are quite vague and would not be considered proofs by today's standards.

Comment: Stanley calls it a proof, albeit "lengthy and indirect." If MacMahon's proof is unsatisfactory, then the next published proof (about 15 years later) seems to be T. W. Chaundy, "Partition-generating functions," *Quarterly J. Math. (Oxford)* **2** (1931), 234-240. But Chaundy does not say anything to suggest that MacMahon's proof was vague or incomplete.